# iOS Grab Phone Notifications

Tags: ios

Ok so this is a very naive question from a complete noobie in iOS. So theoretically in the hypothetical that your App on an Iphone was closed (not running), would it be possible to track notifications and store the text from different the apps making them (Ex. tracking the app that the notification came from, and the message it had in it and possibly storing it in an `NSString` array or string)?

Comment: There is no way to access any data that isn't directed to or from your app.  This includes, but is not limited to, notifications, email, phone records of any kind and what you had for breakfast.

Comment: Really, is there some option to allow a user to consent to taking information from other apps or is that still impossible to achieve?

Comment: *There is **no** way*...

Comment: This isn't even close to something you can do. Apple cares about security and allowing what you want to happen would be the worst decision that Apple has made in decades.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. Apps are sandboxed and Apple goes to great lengths to ensure the security of user data and that their applications don’t share data with other apps installed on the user’s device. Each app has access to its own files, preferences, and network resources.